# Ler e serializar infos de um arquivo na saída em formato JSON com Newtonsoft

Tags: c#

Galera,

Estou tentando deixar mais bonitinho meu programa Console Aplication serializando o resultado final em formato Json com os atributos da classe mas não estou conseguindo direto usando List em c#. O programa lê as informações, mas o resultado esta vindo assim:

```
"1,Leandro Azevedo,Sertanejo"
"2,Clecios Camacho,Heavy Metal\t "
```

mas quero que venha como abaixo usando minha classe que criei:

```
[{"id":"1",
"NomeCompleto":"Leandro Azevedo",
"EstiloMusical":"Sertanejo"},
{"id":"2",
"NomeCompleto":"Clecios Camacho",
"EstiloMusical":"Heavy Metal"}]
```

Tentei usar List para criação dos objetos mas alguns exemplos que vi não rolou muito bem, segue o projeto abaixo:

O arquivo txt contém as informações:

```
1,Leandro Azevedo,Sertanejo
2,Clecios Camacho,Heavy Metal
```

Classe:

```
namespace ConsoleApp_LeituraDeArquivoTexto
{
  public class LeituraDeArquivoTexto
  {
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string NomeCompleto { get; set; }
     public string EstiloMusical { get; set; }
  }
 }
```

Programa:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp_LeituraDeArquivoTexto
{
  class Program
  {
     public static string FormatoJson(string json)
     {
         string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
         return jsonData;
     }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String lerArquivo = @"C:\Estudos\C#\ConsoleApp_LeituraDeArquivoTexto\ler_arquivo.txt";

        string[] linhasLidas = File.ReadAllLines(lerArquivo);

        if (linhasLidas.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ARQUIVO EM BRANCO");
        }
        else
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter escreverLinhaJson = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Estudos\C#\ConsoleApp_LeituraDeArquivoTexto\Resultado.txt"))
            {
                foreach (var linha in linhasLidas)
                {
                    if (linha != "")
                    {
                        string serializarDadosJson = FormatoJson(linha);
                        escreverLinhaJson.WriteLine(serializarDadosJson);
                    }
                }
            }
        
            
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -4):

Pessoal como foi considerado irrelevante minha pergunta, queria fazer era algo do tipo como abaixo, ao invés do artquivo txt usei lista mesmo para serializar a informação em Json, mas valeu o desafio segue abaixo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp_LeituraDeListaConversaoJson
{
class Program
{
    public static string FormatoJson(List<string> json)
    {
        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
        return jsonData;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> listaVideoGames = new List<string>
        {
            "Starcraft",
            "Halo",
            "Legend of Zelda"
        };

        if (listaVideoGames.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lista vazia");
        }
        else
        {
            
            string serializarDadosJson = FormatoJson(listaVideoGames);
            Console.WriteLine(serializarDadosJson);            
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```